# smarty.now display incorrect year

Tags: php, date, templates, format, smarty

I'm using smarty template engine and when I use the following function:

```
$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

it gives this result:

```
8115-07-06 16:25
```

when it should be:

```
2021-07-06 16:25
```

Comment: Your Smarty syntax is correct and works as expected on my system. Can you output $smarty.now without the modifier and see what you get?

Comment: @RobRuchte hi Rob, when I output $smarty.now withouth format it gives me the following: 1625597834 wich a UNIX timestamp with the correct date.

Comment: OK, that's good. What do you get when you run $smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"? Also, what platform, PHP version and Smarty version is this on?

Comment: Also try $smarty.now|date_format:"%EC" and make sure the result is 20

Comment: @RobRuchte tbh I don't what Happened, it's working properly now. I didn't move anything haha, I guess it was a Bug.